# Drawing a canvas on a canvas with given destination width/height results in distorted image

Tags: javascript, canvas

Basically im trying to load an url or a base64code into a temporary canvas. This canvas Im trying to draw on another canvas with a given destination width and height, but results in a distorted image.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ge3snodn/3/)

```
base64img = '/*base64code..*/'
srcToCanvas(base64img, function(img) {
    var _img = img;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    canvas.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, 200, 200) // comes out distorted
    canvas.drawImage(_img, 200, 0) // works fine
});

function srcToCanvas (src, cb){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        cb(canvas);
    };
    image.src = src
};
```

the first call of `canvas.drawImage` comes out distorted, the second one comes out fine. And as in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) stated, the correct syntax is `ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);` So I really dont understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your code which is causing the issue.

```
cb(canvas);//Should have image passed instead of canvas. Drawimage takes image
//Should be
cb(image);
```

After correcting that you will be able to see the in correct aspect ratio.

Here's working link https://jsfiddle.net/ge3snodn/4/

Comment: ah i get it, and since a newly created canvas has 300x150 dimension, and i stretch it to 200x200 it gets distorted.

Comment: even tho `drawImage` also takes canvas

Answer (score 0):

When you call drawImage with the 3 argument signature drawImage(image, xPos, yPos) the image is not scaled, while the 5 argument signature does scale the image to fit the given dimensions.

When you renderer the image it does not care about the canvas size and will clip any of the image outside the canvas.

To draw the image using the 5 argument drawImage

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width,img.height);
```

To draw at a specific size keeping aspect.

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200,img.height * (200 / img.width));
// or
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0,img.width * (200 / img.height),200);
```

Comment: @11thdimension because you are drawing the image with setting the size in one and the other you are drawing the image by just setting where to draw not the size. `ctx.drawImage(img,x,y)` does not specify what size to draw the image, `ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height)` specifies the size and you are stretching the image when you draw it `ctx.drawImage(_img,0,0,200,200)`, it is not 200 by 200 its is 300 by 150

Comment: 200X200 should appear a perfect square. Issue is that it does not. Please look at my answer.

Comment: @11thdimension The image will be square but the content of the image will not be. Check the image attributes when output to the console _img has a size of 300 by 150